# Hide Spectrum JS Color Picker Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to hide a Spectrum Color Picker Element (not the actual color picking panel, but the button you click on to show the panel itself).

I have a reference to the replaced element, however calling show/hide on that shows and hides the replaced element itself:

```html
<input type="color" />
```

```js
var $el = $("input[type='color']")
$el.spectrum()
$el.hide() // Hides the original input element, not the new color picking element
$el.spectrum('hide') // Hides the color picking panel
```

I have multiple of these color pickers on the page, and I only have references to the original `<input type="color" />` element in Javascript (ie I can't add/remove classes from the new color picking element because I don't know which one corresponds to the `<input />` element.

I'm developing a graphic editor and I need to show hide the button based on what object/shapes/images are selected.

Comment: I don't get the issue.. Why would you want to hide the panel that shows the RGB color palettes but allow the user to click on the picker? Please provide a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and show/explain further.

Comment: Just updated the question, basically I need to show/hide the color picker button based on what objects are selected in the editing canvas. For example if a rectangle is selected it makes sense to show the 'fill color' color picker, but that wouldn't make sense if it was an image that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

So spectrum creates a div with a class name sp-replacer. You can select the class name and set it's css display property to none.

For example:

```
$('.sp-replacer').css('display','none');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gabo. The problem was that I only had a reference to the `<input />` element and there was multiple color pickers on the page, so I can't select `.sp-replacer` because that will select every color picker on the page. I ended up doing this: `$el.next(".sp-replacer").hide()`, where $el is the reference to the `<input />`.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the docs, you can try this:

> $("#picker").spectrum('option', 'showInput', false);